# Не добавляется текст в mssql server через Python

Tags: python, sql-server, кодировка, utf-8

Есть таблица в БД mssql - в ней collation по умолчанию `Cyrillic_General_CI_AI`

Из нее , из проблемной колонки старые текстовые данные отображаются в python как `ÃÁÓÇ ÐÀ ÀÐÊÁ` - это меня не волнует старые данные мне не нужны, просто для информации

Заполняю таблицу новыми данными через python - `pymssql` из `dbf` файла
Большинство колонок нормально заполняются, в т ч данные, которые я привожу к str() которые были цифрами в исходном файле, одна колонка, которая была текстом в исходном файле(из негов  python Нормально отображается кирилица), не принимается в таблицу. Другие колонки varchar заполняются а эта - нет, тоже varchar выдает ошибку:

```
pymssql._mssql.MSSQLDatabaseException: 
(102, b"Incorrect syntax near '\\xe7\\xe2\\xf5\\xfa\\xf2\\xe1 \\xe1\\xf2\\xeb\\xe2'.
DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:
\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")
```

При попытках делать какой то encode, и потом снова str - меняются символы но эти данные все равно не принмиаются... пробовал разные сочетания с encode decode и т д.. sp1251 и прочие..

Подскажите к чему привести эти данные чтобы таблица их сьела

```
  #пробовал тут делать разный encoding utf-8
import pymssql
from dbf_light import Dbf
conn = pymssql.connect(server='serv', user='usr', password='pwd', database='db')
cursor = conn.cursor()




with Dbf.open('sprav2.DBF') as dbf:
   for row in dbf:#   print(row.name, row.id_lpu_rf, row.code,row.region)
          region = str(row.code)[0:2]
          nm = row.name
          # пробовал тут разныет encode к этой строке nm.encode(//)
          #print(nm)

          ext = str(row.id_lpu_rf)
          code = str(row.code)

          conn.cursor().execute("INSERT INTO h_e_meds_rf(created_by_id, name) VALUES(1,"+str(nm)+");")
          # сам код работает, если добавлять другие колонки не , name которые не были строкой в оригинальном дбф
          # пробовал подобрать кодировку через dbfshow меняя исходный файл не вышло
          # напомню старые данные если открывать их тким же execute выглядят так: ÃÁÓÇ ÐÀ ÀÐÊÁ
          # ÃÁÓÇ ÐÀ ÀÐÄÊÁ
          # ÃÁÓÇ ÐÀ "ÀÐÊÊÂÄ"
          # ÃÁÓÇ ÐÀ "ÀÐÊÎÄ ÈÌÅÍÈ Ì. Õ. ÀØÕÀÌÀÔÀ"
       # не смог разобраться какая кодировка у меня в  msssql....





conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: *кодировка по умолчанию Cyrillic_General_CI_AI* Пора бы различать CHARSET и COLLATION. *Incorrect syntax near '\xe7\xe2\xf5\xfa\xf2\xe1 \xe1\xf2\xeb\xe2'.* Сервер говорит, что данные к нему приходят от клиента не в той кодировке.

Comment: это я понял , что не в той кодировке, но как понять в какой надо и как исправить чтобы он принял?

Comment: А где собственно ваш код, которым вы это делаете? Гадать то по чему нужно, если кода нет?